# Cortana skill authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, botframework, cortana, user-information-list

I have enabled the connected service in my Cortana channel (Microsoft) and got the token to the BOT framework. 
Now, I want to retrieve the user details from the token by using the registered client id and secret

Sample code in BOT framework:

```
var authInfo = ((Activity)context.Activity).Entities.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type.Equals("AuthorizationToken"));
            var token = authInfo.Properties["token"].ToString();
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Check [BotAuth](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/tree/master/Node) out. You can retrieve the token choosing a provider:

```
const botauth = require("botauth");
const DropboxOAuth2Strategy = require("passport-dropbox-oauth2").Strategy;

...

 // Initialize with the strategies we want to use
var auth = new botauth.BotAuthenticator(server, bot, {
    secret : "something secret",
    baseUrl : "https://" + WEBSITE_HOSTNAME }
);

// Configure the Dropbox authentication provider using the passport-dropbox strategy
auth.provider("dropbox",
    function(options) {
        return new DropboxOAuth2Strategy(
            {
                    clientID : DROPBOX_APP_ID,
                    clientSecret : DROPBOX_APP_SECRET,
                    callbackURL : options.callbackURL
            },
            function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
                profile.accessToken = accessToken;
                profile.refreshToken = refreshToken;
                done(null, profile);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

If you just want to retrieve user name and ID you can get it from [userData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/get-user-profile-context) object:

```
UserInfo : { "Name": { "GivenName": "XYZ", "FamilyName": "ABC" }, "Id": "something@outlook.com" }
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3242